# Python crawling JSON - Getting all items back

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, request, web-crawler

I'm currently facing the problem that I'm not able to scrape the information that I want from a particular website.

In detail, I would like to get all the items and prices back of the sightseeings which are in the JSON.

So far I'm able to get all the prices back, but lacking to get all the items back as well. I'm just getting one particular item back.

Not sure what the problem is.

That is my logic so far:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.cookies.get_dict()
url = 'http://www.citydis.com'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1)    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
response = session.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
metaConfig = soup.find("meta",  property="configuration")


jsonUrl = "https://www.citydis.com/s/results.json?&q=London&   customerSearch=1&page=0"
js_dict = (json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8')))


for item in js_dict:
   header = (js_dict['searchResults']["tours"])
   for titles in header:
       title_final = (titles.get("title"))



   url = (js_dict['searchResults']["tours"])
   for urls in url:
       url_final = (urls.get("url"))


   price = (js_dict['searchResults']["tours"])
   for prices in price:
       price_final = (prices.get("price")["original"])

       print("Header: " + title_final + " | " + "Price: " + price_final)
```

That's the output:

```
   Header: Ticket für Madame Tussauds London &amp; Star-Wars-Erlebnis | Price: 83,66 €
 Header: Ticket für Madame Tussauds London &amp; Star-Wars-Erlebnis | Price: 37,71 €
 Header: Ticket für Madame Tussauds London &amp; Star-Wars-Erlebnis | Price: 152,01 €
```

As you guys can see, the prices are displayed correctly but the items(headers) do not differ. I'm just getting one particular item back.

Could you guys help me out? Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loops are incorrect. You would have only 1 (the last one) `title_final` for each of your `prices in price`, hence the issue.

You may want to do -

```
for item in js_dict:
   headers = js_dict['searchResults']["tours"]
   prices = js_dict['searchResults']["tours"]

   for title, price in zip(headers, prices):
       title_final = titles.get("title")
       price_final = prices.get("price")["original"]
       print("Header: " + title_final + " | " + "Price: " + price_final)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciate it. But now I´m getting the following error for prices.get:     price_final = prices.get("price")["original"]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'     You got any advice on that? Sorry, I´m new to python

Answer (score 1):

```
for titles in header:
    title_final = (titles.get("title"))
```

This code runs, and at the end of it, `title_final` has a single value, and the code moves on to the next thing. Python doesn't magically keep track of all the values that were assigned to a variable and then link different for loops together. You need to do everything in a single loop or store the data in lists and combine them with `zip` or something.

```
for item in js_dict:
```

You're not using `item`. You're just getting things straight from the dictionary inside the loop:

```
(js_dict['searchResults']["tours"])
```

And you're repeating that three times, so `header == url == price`.

Stop and think about your code. Put `print` statements here and there to see what's happening and what the values of variables are.